# Related to clean data either in tableau Or in Alteryx Or in Excel to process report on tableau

Tags: excel, pivot-table, tableau-desktop, alteryx, tableau-prep

[image: THis is the data table]
We have above the data so we want to find out indicator wise if indicator is due Or over due Or completed status. Where over due will be after 30 days from the day it started. So this all data is pure string as team was using excel to manually upload the data. Please help me understand which tool i use to first fix this and covert it into date and then upload in tableau to get meaningful result.   x represent that its next run date for this indicator

(X- 111 and so on) with green color represent that indicator task completed
(X- 111 and so on) without green represent that working on this indicator task
x represent that its next run date is in this month.
Frequency is when its due

How can resolve these data as they are not date just a string data that was added manually in excel sheet and prepared to check the progress but actually we are not able to define the progress. these all names jan feb mar are done manually and even x as well. So basically we want to know how to create future date using this data so if ( e indicator is showing next due date in month of october  and frequency is annual , So it means this indicator previous run date was last year in october, and same goes for quaterly , biannual and monthly data) we are only looking for indicator which have active status. PLease help to fix this complex issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring your excel file directly into Tableau and then edit the data types there. Since all of yours are strings there will be a small icon on your column header of ***Abc*** click the dropdown next to it and choose the correct data type for that column's data.

[image: See Example here]

See the [Data Type Tableau Documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_typesandroles_datatypes.htm) for more info.